# How use if and elif inline on a print()?

Tags: python

I'm trying print an `elif` inline of `print()`.

I've seen some examples like this.

```
print (True if a else False)
```

but I really need this

```
for i in range (0,3):
    for j in range(0,4):
        print(f'Ecuation{i}')
        print(f'X if j==1 Y elif j==2 Z elif j==3' else RESULT)
```

I'm not sure if it's right or possible.

Comment: `f'X if j==1 Y elif j==2 Z elif j==3'` is a string, not a statement.  and only expressions can go into the a =b if x else c syntax, not statements.

Comment: It is far better to define ```X```, ```Y``` and ```Z``` as a variable if a condition is met, and then printing said variable, this way you can use them elsewhere once allocated.

Answer (score 1):

Put the info into a var like this:

```
show = """ if whatever : it """
print(show)
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible using dicts and format string but probably not the best idea.

```py
for i in range(0, 3):
    for j in range(0, 4):
        print(f"Execution {i}")
        print(f'{ {1: "X", 2: "Y", 3: "Z"}.get(j, "RESULT") }')
```

I would recommend Lucas' approach and do a variable outside.

```py
lookups = {1: "X", 2: "Y", 3: "Z"}
for i in range(0, 3):
    for j in range(0, 4):
        print(f"Execution {i}")
        print(f'{ lookups.get(j, "RESULT") }')
```

Note a dictionaries `.get(key, default)` method will attempt to get the `key`. If the `key` is not in the dict then it will return the `default` value. Thus your else.

Answer (score 0):

There are no inline `elif` statements in python. If you need a one-liner, you should use `if...else` statements:

```
for i in range(0, 3):
    for j in range(0, 4):
        print(f'Ecuation{i}')
        print(f'{"X" if j == 1 else ("Y" if j == 2 else ("Z" if j == 3 else "RESULT"))}')
```